# Eventbrite API - event_search - finding best matches

Tags: api, events, search, eventbrite

i've noticed that for certain keywords, the Eventbrite website shows relevant events, but the API returns a lot of irrelevant events.

some examples are: "arts", "health", "auction"

the results shown on the website all have the keywords appearing in the Title/Name of the event, however the API returns events as long as the keywords are in the title and/or description.

MY QUESTION IS: how do I use the API to only get back events which have the keyword appearing in the title?

I'm trying to get the best matching events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[event_search](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search) currently does a full-text search over the title and description fields.

Eventbrite is currently working on connecting their [event_search](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search) interface to the same back-end that powers their [web-based directory service](http://eventbrite.com/directory)

I'm sure they'll make an announcement via [@EventbriteAPI](http://twitter.com/EventbriteAPI) when it's ready.

Comment: thanks! any approx timeline on this? i'm asking because I can't include the eventbrite API in my service until the above is done, as currently the API returns a lot of irrelevant events.

Comment: It's not ideal, but you could try doing some additional matching / filtering on your side - allowing you to reduce the result set to title matches only.
I'll update here when I hear about an ETA for the new search back-end.  Not sure if the ability to match on title only will be included in that release...